# Request keeps saying the data is missing

Tags: laravel, vue.js, request, single-page-application

I'm building a single-page-application website that posts recipes. I'm using Laravel 5.8 & Vue.js

Whenever I'm posting a recipe it keeps saying that the Ingredients and the Directions is missing.

I've already double checked everything, I checked if there's a typo or anything.

I've already done this once from other project, I just copied the code and it was working perfectly well to the other one.

[Here's the images of errors and the vuejs console. You can see there that the ingredients and directions isn't null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qEQb.jpg)

Models required to add a recipe

**RecipeController.php**

```php
public function create()
{
    $form = Recipe::form();

    return response()
        ->json([
               'form' => $form,
          ]);
}
```

**Recipe.php**

```php
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Recipe extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'name', 'slug', 'description', 'category_id',  'thumbnail'
    ];

    public static function form()
    {
        return [
            'name' => '',
            'slug' => '',
            'category_id' => '',
            'description' => '',
            'thumbnail' => '',
            'ingredients' => [
                RecipeIngredient::form()
            ],
            'directions' => [
                RecipeDirection::form(),
                RecipeDirection::form()
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**RecipeDirection.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RecipeDirection extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'description'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public static function form()
    {
        return [
            'description' => ''
        ];
    }
}
```

**RecipeIngredient.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RecipeIngredient extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'recipe_id', 'name', 'qty', 'description'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public static function form()
    {
        return [
            'name' => '',
            'qty' => '',
            'description' => ''
        ];
    }
}
```

```html
**Ingredient**
<div v-for="(ingredient, index) in form.ingredients" v-bind:key="ingredient.id">
    <div>
       <button class="uk-float-right m-t-10 m-b-10" uk-close @click="remove('ingredients', index)" style="font-size: 18px;"></button>
       <div class="uk-grid-small m-t-10" uk-grid>
          <div>
             <input type="text"  class="uk-input uk-input-small m-b-10" v-model="ingredient.qty"  placeholder="Quantity">
          </div>
       <div>
       <input type="text" class="uk-input m-b-10" v-model="ingredient.name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="uk-input" v-model="ingredient.description" placeholder="Description">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
//

**Direction**
<div class="m-b-10" v-for="(direction, index) in form.directions" v-bind:key="direction.id">
    <div>
        <button class="uk-align-right m-b-10" uk-close @click="remove('directions', index)" style="font-size: 18px;"></button>
        <textarea type="text" class="uk-textarea" v-model="direction.description" rows="4" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
export default {

        data() {
            return {
                isProcessing: false,
                form: {
                    ingredients: [],
                    directions: []
                },
                categories: [],
                error: null,
                errors: {},
                has_error: null,
                initializeURL: `/admin/recipes/create`,
                storeURL: `/admin/recipes`,
                action: 'create'
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getForm()
        },
        methods: {
            getForm() {
                if (this.$route.meta.mode === 'edit') 
                {
                    this.initializeURL = `/admin/recipes/${this.$route.params.id}/edit`
                    this.storeURL = `/admin/recipes/${this.$route.params.id}?_method=PUT`
                    this.action = 'update'
                }
                this.$http({
                    url: this.initializeURL,
                    method: 'GET'
                }).then((res) => {
                    Vue.set(this.$data, 'form', res.data.form)
                    this.categories = res.data.categories
                })
            },
            save() {
                this.isProcessing = true
                const form = toMultipartedForm(this.form, this.$route.meta.mode)
                this.$http.post(this.storeURL, form)
                    .then((res) => {
                        if (res.data.saved) 
                        {
                            if (this.$route.meta.mode === 'edit') 
                            {
                                this.$router.push(`/admin/recipes/${this.$route.params.id}/show`)   
                            } else {
                                this.$router.push(`/admin/recipes`)
                            }
                            this.$swal({
                                type: 'success',
                                text: res.data.message
                            })
                        }
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        if (err.response.status === 422) 
                        {
                            this.$swal({
                                type: 'error',
                                text: 'An error has occured'
                            })
                            this.error = err.response.data.error
                            this.errors = err.response.data.errors
                            this.has_error = true
                        }
                        this.isProcessing = false
                    })
            },
            addDirection() {
                this.form.directions.push({
                    description: ''
                })
            },
            addIngredient() {
                this.form.ingredients.push({
                    qty: '',
                    name: '',
                    description: ''
                })
            },
            remove(type, index) {
                if (this.form[type].length > 1) {
                    this.form[type].splice(index, 1)
                }
            }
        },

    }
```

Comment: I don't get it. You're just returning empty arrays in the models. Also in the first model you're using a class without specifing its namespace, isn't it giving you errors?

Comment: See new edit. I'm passing those to my controller then passing it to my Form.vue.

Comment: Yeah and those methods in the model are just formatting arrays that returns nothing so it makes sense that you get empty arrays.

Comment: Sovled it, I fricking have a typo in my form.js. Crazy.